# Is there a way in Rails to say "run all the validates EXCEPT :password"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, passwords, devise

I am using Devise for my authentication. If a `hashed_password` isn't set, Rails/Devise's validations will require a password to be set, as well as the `password_confirmation`.

When I invite new users, I obviously don't want to set their password, so when I create the invitation in my system, it fails because `user.password` is blank.

I can set a temporary `hashed_password` on the user, but when they enter their own password, the validation checks for `:password` and `:password_confirmation` will not happen because `hashed_password` is set, which is a real problem.

Is there any way to tell Rails that I want to run all the validations except for the ones associated with `:password`?

I know Rails has `:if` conditions, which might fix my problem, but Devise declares the `:password` validation on my behalf, so that essentially is hidden.

How can I get the desired result here?, hopefully in a way that is not a hack.

My current hypothetical solution that is somewhat messy: The only thing I can think of is to create a new Invitation model that is not the User model, and use the Invitation model for the form. When the invitation is submitted I can validate that Invitation and copy over all the values to the new User model. I can save that User without any validations at all.

That's the best solution I dreamed up.

It seems like my solution will be a lot more work than saying something simple like:

```
user.save(validations => {:except => :password})
```

**EDIT:** I have found one part of the solution, but I am still having problems. In our user model, we can override a Devise method to prevent the validation of the password for invitations with this bit of code:

```
#protected
def password_required?
  !is_invited && super
end
```

The `is_invited` attribute is just a column I added to the `users` table/model.

However, there is one gotcha here. When a user accepts an invitation and they arrive to the form where they need to set their password/password_confirmation, `valid?` will *always* return `true`.

This one has me deeply perplexed. I don't see how `requires_password?` and `valid?` can be true at the same time. If it requires the password, it should do a validation check and cause the validations to fail.

I'm starting to hate Devise - or just the idea of using gems to build parts of your application in a blackbox. I think the real solution probably is to rip out Devise and just do it all from scratch. That way your app has total control of how all of this works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently started using this great devise add-on: [**devise_invitable**](https://github.com/rymai/devise_invitable)

It's commonly used so users (or any model) can invite other users to join.

But I adapt it for manually (via an admin panel) invite new potential users to my app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: btw, if I remember well Devise include a method called skip_password!, so you can override your registration methods in your User model and achieve the same result.

Comment: I want to stay away from most of devise's forms. I am finding that they require too much specialization, and I may even swap it out at some point. So for the complex forms, I just started writing the methods myself. I may continue this process and eventually swap it out. The reason is that as much time as it saves me initially, I am finding that the time to figure out how to customize it or tweak it the way I want takes longer than writing the code from scratch. Of course if you've used Devise 5 times, it would be faster, but for a new user... I don't think it is in the end.

Comment: Anyway, back to the task at hand... Devise doesn't seem to include a skip_password!, but it does include a password_required? method that one can override. I guess I will have to create this method and use a variable to configure it.

Comment: Customizing rails generators like Devise isn't that hard, it often involves overriding the needed methods (a.k.a. Monkey Patching http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). Look this example I made for sending a welcome messaging when Users confirm their accounts: https://gist.github.com/982181